# R logistic regression throwing error

Tags: r, regression, logistic, sas

I have data with 6 predictor variables and a response variable (*default* ). When I do a logistic regression using ***probit estimation***, I get a result different from SAS.

(*the link to my data* https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TZvEsOpuzLQ_BvGBR26n5M-yzlp2yUWH)

```
equation <- as.formula(default ~ dlagR3+loglaginf6+dloglagImp6+loglagRR9+dlagFX6+laglogRGDP6 )

model    <- glm(equation , family = binomial('probit'), data=setDF(data))
```

But R is giving the following error:

```
 glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
  (Intercept) -5.13523    1.55705  -3.298 0.000974 ***
  dlagR3       0.04719    0.03696   1.277 0.201711    
  loglaginf6  -0.39395    0.05637  -6.989 2.76e-12 ***
  dloglagImp6  0.13151    0.02981   4.412 1.02e-05 ***
  loglagRR9    6.78246    0.09228  73.497  < 2e-16 ***
  dlagFX6      0.02099    0.01835   1.144 0.252535    
  laglogRGDP6 -1.52335    0.32653  -4.665 3.08e-06 ***
```

But when I use ***SAS*** or ***Eviews***, this error is not thrown and they both agree on the coefficients. 
[image: SAS Output]

[image: Eviews Output]

So I tried implementing a lot of supposed solutions as given in a lot of forums but no matter what I do, R is giving the same coefficients. The results given by Eviews and SAS is the accurate one.

**Note:** SAS gives the probability of 0 (not 1) so I have created a new response variable *default2* which is opposite of default

```
proc logistic data=data;
model default2 = dlagR3 loglaginf6 dloglagImp6 loglagRR9 dlagFX6 laglogRGDP6 
/link=probit;
run;
```

Comment: There might be complete or quasi-complete separation in your data, which will effect the maximum likelihood estimates.  SAS must have a different way of dealing with that (I don't know much about the other software you use).

Comment: @DemetriPananos That's fine. I tried using a lot of solutions to variable separation but they don't seem to be working.

Comment: The thing is that no matter whichever alternate function i use, the coefficients are all same and they don't change

Comment: See this answer.  Seems like this person has the same problem.  One answer talks about PROC LOGISTIC https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you remove some predictors from the model?  Try regressing on just one or two variables.  Do the results look the same between the three?

Comment: Okay. Never tried that @DemetriPananos

Comment: I'm interested in what happens when you fir the model without loglagRR9

Comment: @DemetriPananos hi I tried removing loglagRR9, and R did not throw the error but its still not matching with SAS

Comment: Does the log in SAS say that it has detected separation?

Comment: @DemetriPananos Hi. No it doesn't say that

Comment: You use the "as.formula" and "setDF(data)"... Have you tried including formula and data reference the -old simple- way in your glm() function?

Comment: @Tomas Yes, I have